# Convert Plot to Base64

Tags: export, image, web-access

My goal is to get a Base64 string directly from a plot (or any `Graphics` object) in Mathematica such that, when using a Base64 decoder online, [such as this one](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter), I get back the image of my plot.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe something like this?: `s = ExportString[Compress[im], {"Base64", "Text"}, 
   CharacterEncoding -> "ISO8859-1"];
Uncompress@
 ImportString[s, {"Base64", "Text"}, CharacterEncoding -> "ISO8859-1"]` -- not completely sure what you're after.

Comment: How about `str = ExportString[im, {"Base64", "WDX"}]`?

Comment: What are you trying to do this for? Is there any importance of "Base64"? If you just need to represent the plota as a string to be reloaded in Mathematica, using `Compress` and `Uncompress` will work pretty well...

Comment: I think this question can't be answered productively before Albert's comment is addressed. It looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: My goal is to get a `Base64` string directly from a plot (or any `Graphics` object) in Mathematica such that, when using a Base64 decoder online, for example, I get back the image of my plot. Interesting concept, the XY problem! This is the first time I'm using Base64, so I apologise for any bad phrasing or misconceptions, but I hope this clarifies what I actually want.

Comment: The online decoder would need to 'understand' what's been decoded to 'give' you the image. `Graphics[...]` is a WL language expression which Mathematica can render appropriately. If you want to show it outside then it needs to be converted to e.g. SVG or PNG. E.g.: `ExportString[img, {"Base64", "PNG"}]`

Comment: I rewrote the question to make it clear what you want to do. Please edit if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Online services, such as the one referenced in the question, require the image to be in one of the standard web formats (PNG, JPEG, etc.)

First you must export the graphics into one of these image formats. This gives you a string of bytes (a file). Base64 is a way to encode a string of arbitrary bytes into a string of ASCII characters.

As Kuba mentions, the entire process can be done in one step as

```
pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]

base64 = ExportString[pl, {"Base64", "JPEG"}]
```

Now copy it and use it with the online decoder:

```
CopyToClipboard[base64]
```